# How to hide input panel in another form in compact framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have application with 2 forms in compact framework.
First main form has mainmenu and input panel control. On main form is button, when I click it second form is showed. Second form has mainmenu but without input panel.
The problem is with input panel on second form. When I show second form the input panel is still enable. And when I click the input panel on second form this form disapear. I want to have second form without input panel, only with main menu. On main menu is button which work correct.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This code will enable you to enable /  disable the Input Panel.  By input panel I presume you mean the Soft Input Panel Keyboard.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
private void EnableSip()
{
          SoftKeyboard.CurrentInputMethod = SoftKeyboard.CurrentInputMethod;
          SoftKeyboard.Enabled = true;
          SoftInputPanel.ShowSIP(true, this);
}
private void DisableSip()
 {
          SoftKeyboard.Enabled = false;
          SoftInputPanel.ShowSIP(false, this);
 }
```